$SET-COVER\leq_pIP$
Let:
$IP=\left \{ \left \langle A,b \right \rangle \right \}:$ $A$ is a $m\times l$ matrix over the integers, $b$ is a vector of $m$ integers and there exists a vector $x$ of $l$ integers s.t $Ax\geq b$.
Note that $Ax$ and $b$ are both m-dimensional vectors.
When writing $Ax\geq b$ the meaning is the inequality holds in each coordinate.
$SET-COVER=\left \{ \left \langle U,S_1,\ldots,S_m,k \right \rangle \right \}:$ $U$ is a set of integers, $S_1,\ldots,S_m\subseteq U$ and there exists a subset $A\subseteq \left \{ 1,\ldots,m \right \}$ s.t $\left | A \right |=k \; \wedge \; \bigcup_{i\in A}S_i=U$.
The question asked to show $SET-COVER\leq_pIP$
I'm stuck mainly on the part of $x$ in $IP$ - all my attempts converged to failure because I was able to increase $x$ as much as I wanted in order to get $Ax\geq b$.

Given $(U, S_1, …, S_m, k)$ an input of Set-Cover, with $U = \{1, …, n\}$, consider an $n\times m$ matrix with $0$-$1$ coefficients, such that $A_{ij}$ represents $i\in S_j$.
Consider $b$ an $n$-vector with only $1$'s.
Can you see the link between the two problems?
Note that this is not the complete solution, since you have to modify those matrices to add a condition on $k$.
First, you want coefficients of $x$ to be either $0$'s or $1$'s. That means that for all $i$, $x_i \geqslant 0$ and $-x_i\geqslant -1$.

 You just need to add $2m$ lines in the matrix $A$, each containing either $1$ or $-1$ at the right position, and $2m$ lines to the vector $b$, with either $0$ or $1$.

For the condition that the subset of $[\![1,m]\!]$ must be of size $\leqslant k$, that means that $\sum x_i\leqslant k$.

 How to do it? Add a line of $-1$ in the matrix $A$, and a line $-k$ in the matrix $b$. Indeed, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m(-1)\times x_i \geqslant -k\Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_{i=1}^mx_i \leqslant k$.


Thank you for basically the answer! I just don't understand the following one thing. There are some constrains on the $x$ vector on $IP$. Say $$x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1\ \vdots \ x_m \end{pmatrix}$$As I understood: $$\underset{1\leq j\leq m}{\forall j} x_j\in\left { 0,1 \right } \wedge \sum_{j=1}^{m}x_j \leq k$$How I tell the computable function that I defined to take into consideration those constrains ?

That's up to you to find out! Note that what I gave is not the answer, since you must modify the matrix to verify the constraints you described. You should add a line to $A$ and to $b$.

The furthest I've been able to go is: The last row in $A$ will be of 1's. The added row in $b$ will be with the value of $k$. From matrix multiplication, the last row in $Ax$ will be with value $k$ if we choose exactly $k$ rows in the $x$ vector (i.e., set their values to 1 and the rest to 0).

The one thing I can't figure out is how I tell the function $$\underset{1\leq j\leq m}{\forall j} x_j\in\left { 0,1 \right } \wedge \sum_{j=1}^{m}x_j \leq k$$I tried using modulo 2 for telling the function to puts $0,1$ in $A$ and $x$, but the multiplication of the two is where I got stuck - If I will continue using modulo 2, I won't be able to get the last row of $Ax$ to $k$

@Daniel I edited my answer with the whole solution.

Thank you very much for the time and help, I really apricate it !!
